# Calculations inside html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to multiply the "quantity" inputted by the user by 1 item chosen from a dropdown list (the prices of the items must be saved in an array). Also, when the user chooses a different item a picture on the right changes. I'm having a problem making the quantity*item function since I'm a total beginner in JavaScript/HTML. Please no jQuery code, purely JavaScript/HTML. Below is a piece of the code. Anyone can help me fix it please? Thanks.

JavaScript:

```
function swapImage(dropdown){
    var value= dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    var edit_save = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
    edit_save.src = value;
    alert(value);
}

var priceList = new Array(4);
pricelist[0]=10;
pricelist[1]=12;
pricelist[2]=14;
pricelist[3]=11;    

function calculateTotal(dropdown){
    var total=priceList[dropdown.selectedIndex]*number;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img id="imageToSwap" src="gnar.png" alt="CSS Style Tag">

<br><br>

<select id="dlist" onchange="swapImage(this)">
    <option value=gnar.png>Gnar Hoodie €10</option>
    <option value=blitz.png>Blitz T-Shirt €12</option>
    <option value=corki.png>Corki Hoodie €14</option>
    <option value=graves.png>Graves T-Shirt €11</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<label name="Quantity">Quantity of the item</label> 
<input type="number" name="Quantity" min="1" required=""><br>

<p class="totals" id="totalprice">Total Price:</p>
```

Comment: Your `calculateTotal()` function doesn't return anything, nor does it update the dom in any way, what were you expecting? Also, where are you calling it?

Comment: You will need to set the same name : `priceList` with a upper case L everywhere: you have `pricelist[...]=...` with a lower case l...

Comment: You are also missing a semi-colon at the line where you define `priceList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a http://jsfiddle.net/p5rmpjet/7/. I changed it up a bit so the prices are stored in your ids in your html instead of adding them to your JS every time you have a new item.

```
function swapImage(e){
   var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
   console.log(image);  //image tag
   image.src = e.value;
}

function updatePrice(quantity){
   var edit_save = document.getElementById("dlist");
   console.log(edit_save.options[ edit_save.selectedIndex].id); //price of item

   var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
   console.log(quantity);

   var price = edit_save.options[edit_save.selectedIndex].id;

   var total = quantity * price;
   console.log(total);
   document.getElementById("totalprice").innerHTML = total;
 }

 function updateItem(price){
    var price = edit_save.options[edit_save.selectedIndex].id;
 }
```

**NOTE: Updated fiddle** with a second function on the onchange event for selecting items http://jsfiddle.net/p5rmpjet/7/

Comment: Omg thanks it works fine but is there a way to update the total price instantly? Because if you change the quantity after you chose an item the price won't change

Comment: @CarlCarl I updated it to cover item selection as well as quantity, but if you that change that's great. You're welcome, glad it worked out. Don't forget to accept the answer.